# How to access protected inner class outside package?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, inner-classes

```
package p1;

public class demo1{

     public static void main(String []args){

     }
     protected class demo12{

         protected  int fun2(int a,int b){

             return a*b;
     }

}

package p2;
import p1.demo1;
public class demo2{

     public static void main(String []args){
         //access fun2 method here.
     }    

}
```

I create a package `p1` and create a inner class name `demo12`. And i want to access `demo12` `fun2` method in package `p2`. How to do it?

Do any change in class `demo2`. And directly or indirectly I want to access that method from class `demo2` without change code of `demo1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to access your `demo12` inner class from `demo2` class, `demo2` class has to extend `demo1`. More over, inner classes are connected with instances of the class, so you can not call it directly from the static method.

Check the difference between [inner and nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

> **Static Nested Classes**
>
> As with class methods and variables, a static nested class is
>   associated with its outer class. And like static class methods, a
>   static nested class cannot refer directly to instance variables or
>   methods defined in its enclosing class: it can use them only through
>   an object reference.
>
> **Inner Classes**
>
> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated
>   with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that
>   object's methods and fields. Also, because an inner class is
>   associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members
>   itself.

*Edited:*

I would suggest to check your design whether it class hierarchy cannot be simplified. Especially focus on difference between inner and static nested classes.

Your inner class `demo12` is also marked protected, you can extend it as well. Check this hack:

```
package p2;

import p1.demo1;

public class demo2 extends demo1 {

    protected int foo( int a, int b ) {
        return (new demo22()).fun2(a, b);
    }

    protected class demo22 extends demo12 {
        protected int fun2( int a, int b ) {
            return super.fun2(a, b);
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        (new demo2()).foo(2, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to do it indirectly? Can you tell me ? I tried but i can only access protected class not the method.

Comment: I have extended answer.

Comment: You just create same method in demo22. I understand your hack.  But can there is other way we can access fun2 without create same method in demo22 class? Thank you for this one....@Maciej Lach

Comment: The `demo22.fun2()` should call method from `demo12` via `super`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `demo2` should inherit `demo1`:

```
class demo2 extends demo1 {...}
```

Comment: Do anything with class demo2 but tell me how to access fun2?

Comment: see @Maciej Lach answer