# How do I access a protected inner class from another package?

Tags: java, class, object, oop, inner-classes

How do I access inner class "Inner" in "file1" in package "secret" from "file2" in package "test". Here is the code for it:

```
package secret;

public class file1 {
    protected class Inner {
        public int x = 8;
    }
}
```

```
package test;
import secret.file1;

public class file2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // code
    }
}
```

I am aware that there is a similar question on this topic ([How to access protected inner class outside package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964592/how-to-access-protected-inner-class-outside-package)) but I didn't seem to understand the answers. Here is what I have tried so far (from reading the answers):

First attempt:

```
public class file2 extends file1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        file1 outer = new file1();
        file1.Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
    }
}
```

Second attempt:

```
public class file2 extends file1 {
    public static class file3 extends file1.Inner {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            file1 outer = new file1();
            file1.Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
        }
    }
}
```

Attempt 3:

```
public class file2 extends file1 {
    public static class file3 extends file1.Inner {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            file2 outer = new file2();
            file2.file3 outerinner = outer.new file3();
            file2.file3.Inner inner = outerinner.new Inner();
        }
    }
}
```

There definitely seems like I'm missing something, guiding me in the right direction would be much apricated.

Comment: By using Reflection.  The real question, though, is why do you need to?

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround by using third class:

```java
package secret;

public class file3 extends file1 {
    public Inner createInner(){
        return new Inner();
    }
}
```

then simply:

```java
public class file2 extends file1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        file3 outer = new file3();
        file1.Inner inner = outer.createInner();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your class hierarchy design whether it  cannot be simplified.put your main focus on the difference between inner and static nested classes.
or come up with something like this file1 x = new inner();